# How to drag and drop before or after element using java

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a drag and drop website. But I'm facing a problem to drop the element before or after, above or below the other element. I have watched a tutorial about it that's working but I cannot attach the code to my code as I'm totally new to java. Here is my drag and drop code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

<button  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">btn1</button>
<button  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">btn2</button>
<button  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">btn3</button>
 
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer in javascript please

Comment: Do you want the answer in Java or Javascript. As both are 2 different languages.

Comment: [Please note that JavaScript and Java are two completely separate programming languages that are related in name only](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_javascript.html).

Comment: answer in javascript

Comment: You have 2 different functions with same name, `drag(ev)` rename one of the function and update where it's called.

Comment: will these two not work together as this is only the sollution came in my mind. If you know well please help and with my problem too

Comment: @AbhishekGowda28 one is drag(ev) and another is drop(eV) isn't it ?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @AwaisAli You have ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); in the drop method. This will always append the child in your destination div. You might need to right some more code to find out where the element is being dropped and then insert the new element in between instead of appending everytime.

Comment: It may be helpful top link to the Tutorial that you saw. I might also suggest a framework like jQuery UI where Drag and Drop is made a lot easier to setup.

Comment: here's the link https://codepen.io/WebDevSimplified/pen/JjdveeV to the tutorial code can you help to link it as I don't have much knowledge of javascript